# Why using the keyword raise in initialize constructor gives an error?

Tags: ruby

I ask this because I was doing a little challenge and all the test cases where failing and I realize that my code was good let me show you what happended.

So I have this piece of code:

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name

  end

  def printName 
    return @name
  end

end

human = Person.new('Josh')

puts human.printName
```

The output its pretty obvious but when I tried to run it the first time I saw that the code has the raise keyword for exceptions, the code was like this and gave me this error:

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    raise "Implement intialize method"

  end

  def printName 
    return @name
    raise "Implement print method"
  end

end

human = Person.new('Josh')

puts human.printName
```

Output:
`initialize': Implement intialize method (RuntimeError)`

As soon as I deleted the raise keyword from the constructor the testcases were successful, **can someone explain me why this happens?**

Answer (score 0):

The `raise` method of the kernel, basically raises an [exception or RuntimeError](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) when it is set in your code... seems like the challenge expected you to implement those methods (implying you would remove the raise call)